# Which font does LaTeX use / Possible to use in Word?

Tags: fonts, msword, computer-modern

What is the name of the standard font in LaTeX? And is it possible to download and use this font in Microsoft Word?

I found that Latin Modern supposedly resembled it, but the archives on http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download contain more than 70 different fonts, so I don't know which one to choose.

All I am looking for is a single, say, OTF font file which I can use in Word and which looks exactly like the default latex font.

Comment: You need *all* OTF files. They contain various variants of Latin Modern (family, size, series, shape, etc). If you do not want the mono or the sans-serif one, then don't install them (but you can't use them then either). The file `lmroman10-regular.otf` contains the roman, upright, medium, default size font.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel What do you mean by "you need all OTF files" ? It seems I only need `lmroman10-regular.otf`, right?

Comment: @Thomas Do you want italic shape? Bold series? Bolditalic? Sans-serif family? Typewriter family? (Correct) fonts at different sizes? Small Caps? Semibold? If you can answer all questions with “No”, then yes, you only need `lmroman10-regular.otf`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Okay, this answers my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah. just use latex.